# Vega-Lite: Excessive padding when generating a chart with `vl2svg`

Tags: svg, headless, vega-lite

I'm using vega-lite's `vl2svg` CLI helper to headlessly generate chart SVGs on a Heroku server. This works great for the most part, but I'm noticing that the generated SVGs have way too much padding on the left side, to the left of the labels, and the amount of "excess padding" grows as the labels get longer.

For example, here's a simple bar chart with 3 bars and 3 labels. In the [online Vega-Lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited), the chart renders correctly as pictured below (ie. no excessive padding). But when I generate the same chart via `vl2svg` on my local computer (using the same package versions - Vega 5.21.0, Vega-Lite 5.2.0) the chart has around 100px of excess padding on the left side before the labels begin.

The chart's VL spec:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [{"category":"Male","count":112},{"category":"Female","count":122},{"category":"Other (eg. non-binary)","count":31}]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"field": "category", "sort": null, "title": "", "type": "nominal", "axis": {}},
    "x": {"field": "count", "title": "", "type": "quantitative", "axis": {}}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "bar"},
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "dx": 3, "dy": 0, "xOffset": 0, "yOffset": 0, "align": "left", "baseline": "middle", "limit": 20, "fontSize": 8},
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "count"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Steps I used to generate the svg headlessly (on MacOS 10.15.7, in case the OS matters):

- `npm install vega-lite@5.2.0`
- write the above spec to `test.json`
- `node_modules/vega-lite/bin/vl2svg test.json > test.svg`

The SVG chart rendered by the [online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/edited) (I added the red border to highlight the difference in padding):

[image: Chart generated by the online Vega-Lite editor]

The SVG chart rendered by `vl2svg` run locally:

[image: Same chart generated by vl2svg headlessly / locally]

Why does this difference in padding / spacing exist? What can I do to make the headlessly-generated svg render identically to what the online editor generates? Is this a bug? or user error on my end?

NOTE: The excessive spacing *mostly* disappears when the labels are uniformly short. For example if I reword that third label to "Other", then re-render the svg using `vl2svg`, there's only ~5px of excessive left padding, as shown below:

[image: Chart generated headlessly using vl2svg, with short labels]

Comment: Update: I [reported this](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7956) as a possible bug on the Vega-Lite Github repo but didn't have time/bandwidth to troubleshoot it further. Instead I switched to rendering charts via frontend JS in the browser, to sidestep these padding issues.